# Getting object dependencies in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, serialization, object-serialization

I have an instance of the object which is dependent on other objects, e.g.

```
$objA = new Some_Class();
$objB = new Other_Class();
$objC = new Another_One();

$objA->property = new stdClass;
$objB->key = $objA;
$objB->arr = array(new Other_Object());

$objectC->property = $objB
$objectC->other = array(array('k'=>'v'));
```

How can I get a list of classes used in `$objectC`?

In this particular case:

```
array(
    'Some_Class',
    'Other_Class',
    'Another_Class',
    'stdClass',
    'Another_Object'
)
```

I need to serialize the object, but before unserializing I need to instantiate all the needed classes.
How would you get the classes automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`serialize` isn't shallow, it's deep.

This means that if you call `serialize($objectC);`, you're getting not just $objectC, but also all of it's properties, *including any objects that it might contain*.

If you *must* reinstantiate one of the child objects (let's say it's a database adapter, which contains an unserializable Resource), consider implementing the [Serializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface, which lets you perform fine-grained control over the serialize and unserialize operations that simply isn't possible with the [`__sleep`/`__wakeup`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep) magic methods.  You can use the methods provided by the interface to return a customized data structure that will allow you to manually reconstruct the object, as needed.